# How to change the value of some m x m submatrices from an NxN matrix with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

The general problem I'm facing could be translated as follows:

> Code a NxN matrix in which mxm sub-matrices of values x or y are regularly alternated.

For example, let's say I need to make a 6x6 matrix with 2x2 sub-matrices of 0 or 1 are alternated, the result should be the matrix below:

```
0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
```

For now, I only managed to get this:

```
0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

with the code :

```
b = numpy.zeros((6, 6))
b[:2, 2:6:4] = 1
b[2:6:4, :2] = 1
print(b)
```

I managed to find a solution but it has four for-loop so it is hard to read and takes a bit of time. The code for this possible answer is:

```
c = np.array([])    
for k in range(3):
    for l in range (2):
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range (2):
            
                if (k+i)%2 == 0:
                    c = np.append(c, 0)
                else:
                    c = np.append(c, 1)
print("c = ", np.reshape(c, (6, 6)))
```

Isn't there a better way to give the expected output without using loops or with 1 or 2 loops max ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
m = 8 
n = 4

c = np.zeros(shape=(m,m))    
assert not m%n #m must be divisible by n
for row_i in range(m):
  for col_i in range(m):
    if (row_i//n + col_i//n)%2:
      c[row_i][col_i] = 1

print(c)
```

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with using python array slicing. Here is an example for 2x2 submatrices (works with any even-square sized matrix b).

```
# first block for submatrices starting at column and row index 0

# 0::4 - every 4th column/row starting from column 0
# so this results in 1 0 0 0 1 0 and so on
b[0::4, 0::4] = 1

# 1::4 - every 4th column starting from column 1
# so this results in 0 1 0 0 0 1 and so on
b[0::4, 1::4] = 1

b[1::4, 0::4] = 1
b[1::4, 1::4] = 1

# second block for submatrices starting from column and row index 2 
b[2::4, 2::4] = 1
b[2::4, 3::4] = 1
b[3::4, 2::4] = 1
b[3::4, 3::4] = 1
```

Now for larger submatrices you have just to increase the distance between the entries. For submatrices of size `n`, the distance must be `2 * n`, because that is the sheme for the repetition of `1` in the matrix. Each block then has size `n`. Try to write a procedure. If you do not succeed I will help further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one take using `np.repeat` and `np.tile`:

```
import numpy as np

def tiled_matrix(n, m):
  row = np.tile(np.repeat([1, 0], m), (n // m) // 2 + 1)[:n]
  row_block = np.tile(row, (m,1))
  two_rows_block = np.vstack((row_block, 1 - row_block))
  arr = np.tile(two_rows_block, ((n // m) // 2 + 1, 1))[:n]
  return arr

print(tiled_matrix(10, 4))
# [[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

Here is another take with `np.meshgrid` and `xor`:

```
def meshgrid_mod(n, m):
  ix = np.arange(n, dtype=np.uint8)
  xs, ys = np.meshgrid(ix, ix)
  arr = ((xs % (2*m)) < m) ^ ((ys % (2*m)) < m)
  return arr.astype(np.int)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is probably to use `skimage.util.view_as_blocks()`:

```py
import numpy as np
import skimage.util

a = np.zeros((6, 6))
b = skimage.util.view_as_blocks(a, (2, 2))
# b is a view of a, so changing values in b will also change values in a
b[::2, ::2, ...] = 1
b[1::2, 1::2, ...] = 1

a
# array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
#        [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
#        [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```